# Is is acceptable to push non-working code [git]

Tags: git, coding-style, branch

I understand it's quite normal to commit non-working code in local, and squash+push once it works. 
On a non-master branch however would it be acceptable to push an non-functioning version of the code in order to share with another developer?

Comment: There is unfortunately no right answer to this. What works for one team won't work for another. Voting to close as primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

While using git there should always be a good workflow in wich everybody can co-operate on a nice, structual way. An example to your question would be using multiple branches. The workflow i use is the following.

**Master branch**
The master branch is the branch only consisting of working code in project versions. Only a full working project like project version 2.0 will be `committed` and `pushed` to this branch

**Development**
The `development` branch is the branch where you are developing on. On this branch `not-working` code isn't a problem since only this branch is used for development and the master branch for staging and live.

You could also choose to create a third branch for example called `bugs` on this branch you're able to `push` `commit` and work on `not-working` code.

By using these kind of workflows you're able to keep everything in his own place and organized.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, but keep in mind that once you `push -f` a public branch, someone's work could get lost. If you can coordinate the force pushes with other developers working on the same branch, you might agree to allow it - but keep in mind the risk of loosing work is higher.

It all depends on the workflow and rules you arrange with your team.

Answer (score 0):

I just cannot accept the fact that one would commit a non working code, a commit is suppose to be a snapshot of the code.

It would be difficult -almost impossible- to spot a future regression in the code if one accept to commit non working copies of the code.

If you want to trace back your steps to find which commit introduced a certain bug, you'll find your self going through some commits that just don't compile...

This being said, i cannot even start talking about one pushing a non working copy of a code.

Comment: Local commits are an extension of your editor's undo buffers.  Committing nonworking code while you explore alternative ways to get it working is very handy.  Pushing broken code to a friend's repo on a temp "wtf am I doing wrong here?" ref ain't necessarily a bad thing either.

Comment: Unless you plan on resetting your commit, i don't get it ! if you're working on some solution and at some point you want to leave it at that non working state, don't commit it and leave in history for no reason, you can always stash your current state and not commit it. 

But apparently like the comment on the original question states, there is no right answer for all teams, but in my team ain't nobody committing non working code :)

Comment: reset, rebase, amend, git's a full history editor. make the history that's most useful to whoever's going to be using it. if that's you right now, history's an alternatives explorer. if you think it's ready for production, history's working, publishable commits arranged for maximum clarity.  git's not just for production ready code, it's at least as much for the messy parts that come before that

Comment: jthill, That's how I envisioned it, commit my feature branch to share with a colleague, and amend before merging the functional code.

I share some of the same concerns as TheFuquan however, which is why I'm hesitant to do so.

As it stands I'll start to adopt this only so far as my team are comfortable with it.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure there is a 'right way' (e.g. noy in main but otherwise).  I prefer to always check in compilable code.  I use patch files to share non working changes.

git diff  >output.patch

patch -p0 < output.patch

Note it might be p1 ... posting this away from keyboard. If the patch may stuck around I'll also include the current hash so I know what it was diff'd from.